# boost::multiprecision cast from integer to cpp_dec_float compile error

Tags: c++, boost

I encounter a problem moving some code to a server.

A minimal working example of the problem is the following code (filename `mp2.cpp`):

```
#include <boost/multiprecision/cpp_int.hpp>
#include <boost/multiprecision/cpp_dec_float.hpp>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
using namespace boost::multiprecision;

int main() {
    uint128_t a = 1;
    uint128_t b = 2;
    cpp_dec_float_50 fa = static_cast<cpp_dec_float_50>(a);
    cpp_dec_float_50 fb = static_cast<cpp_dec_float_50>(b);
    cout << fa / fb << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Compiles and works as expected, writing `0.5` on standard output on my dev machine (g++ 4.6.3, boost 1.55, 32 bits CPU).

For the same code, g++ fails compiling on the server with this error:

```
In file included from /usr/local/include/boost/multiprecision/number.hpp:22:0,
                 from /usr/local/include/boost/multiprecision/cpp_int.hpp:12,
                 from mp2.cpp:1:
/usr/local/include/boost/multiprecision/detail/generic_interconvert.hpp: In instantiation of 'void boost::multiprecision::detail::generic_interconvert(To&, const From&, const mpl_::int_<1>&, const mpl_::int_<0>&) [with To = boost::multiprecision::backends::cpp_dec_float<50u>; From = boost::multiprecision::backends::cpp_int_backend<128u, 128u, (boost::multiprecision::cpp_integer_type)0u, (boost::multiprecision::cpp_int_check_type)0u, void>]':
/usr/local/include/boost/multiprecision/number.hpp:108:7:   required from 'boost::multiprecision::number<Backend, ExpressionTemplates>::number(const boost::multiprecision::number<Other, ET>&, typename boost::enable_if_c<(! boost::multiprecision::detail::is_explicitly_convertible<Other, Backend>::value)>::type*) [with Other = boost::multiprecision::backends::cpp_int_backend<128u, 128u, (boost::multiprecision::cpp_integer_type)0u, (boost::multiprecision::cpp_int_check_type)0u, void>; boost::multiprecision::expression_template_option ET = (boost::multiprecision::expression_template_option)0u; Backend = boost::multiprecision::backends::cpp_dec_float<50u>; boost::multiprecision::expression_template_option ExpressionTemplates = (boost::multiprecision::expression_template_option)1u; typename boost::enable_if_c<(! boost::multiprecision::detail::is_explicitly_convertible<Other, Backend>::value)>::type = void]'
mp2.cpp:11:55:   required from here
/usr/local/include/boost/multiprecision/detail/generic_interconvert.hpp:43:4: error: no matching function for call to 'eval_is_zero(boost::multiprecision::backends::cpp_int_backend<128u, 128u, (boost::multiprecision::cpp_integer_type)0u, (boost::multiprecision::cpp_int_check_type)0u, void>&)'
/usr/local/include/boost/multiprecision/detail/generic_interconvert.hpp:43:4: note: candidates are:
In file included from mp2.cpp:2:0:
/usr/local/include/boost/multiprecision/cpp_dec_float.hpp:2905:13: note: template<unsigned int Digits10, class ExponentType, class Allocator> bool boost::multiprecision::backends::eval_is_zero(const boost::multiprecision::backends::cpp_dec_float<Digits10, ExponentType, Allocator>&)
/usr/local/include/boost/multiprecision/cpp_dec_float.hpp:2905:13: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
In file included from /usr/local/include/boost/multiprecision/number.hpp:22:0,
                 from /usr/local/include/boost/multiprecision/cpp_int.hpp:12,
                 from mp2.cpp:1:
/usr/local/include/boost/multiprecision/detail/generic_interconvert.hpp:43:4: note:   'boost::multiprecision::backends::cpp_int_backend<128u, 128u, (boost::multiprecision::cpp_integer_type)0u, (boost::multiprecision::cpp_int_check_type)0u, void>' is not derived from 'const boost::multiprecision::backends::cpp_dec_float<Digits10, ExponentType, Allocator>'
In file included from /usr/local/include/boost/multiprecision/cpp_int.hpp:1787:0,
                 from mp2.cpp:1:
/usr/local/include/boost/multiprecision/cpp_int/misc.hpp:94:4: note: template<unsigned int MinBits1, unsigned int MaxBits1, boost::multiprecision::cpp_integer_type SignType1, boost::multiprecision::cpp_int_check_type Checked1, class Allocator1> typename boost::enable_if_c<(! boost::multiprecision::backends::is_trivial_cpp_int<boost::multiprecision::backends::cpp_int_backend<MinBits, MaxBits, SignType, Checked, Allocator> >::value), bool>::type boost::multiprecision::backends::eval_is_zero(const boost::multiprecision::backends::cpp_int_backend<MinBits, MaxBits, SignType, Checked, Allocator>&)
/usr/local/include/boost/multiprecision/cpp_int/misc.hpp:94:4: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
/usr/local/include/boost/multiprecision/cpp_int/misc.hpp: In substitution of 'template<unsigned int MinBits1, unsigned int MaxBits1, boost::multiprecision::cpp_integer_type SignType1, boost::multiprecision::cpp_int_check_type Checked1, class Allocator1> typename boost::enable_if_c<(! boost::multiprecision::backends::is_trivial_cpp_int<boost::multiprecision::backends::cpp_int_backend<MinBits, MaxBits, SignType, Checked, Allocator> >::value), bool>::type boost::multiprecision::backends::eval_is_zero(const boost::multiprecision::backends::cpp_int_backend<MinBits, MaxBits, SignType, Checked, Allocator>&) [with unsigned int MinBits1 = 128u; unsigned int MaxBits1 = 128u; boost::multiprecision::cpp_integer_type SignType1 = (boost::multiprecision::cpp_integer_type)0u; boost::multiprecision::cpp_int_check_type Checked1 = (boost::multiprecision::cpp_int_check_type)0u; Allocator1 = void]':
/usr/local/include/boost/multiprecision/detail/generic_interconvert.hpp:43:4:   required from 'void boost::multiprecision::detail::generic_interconvert(To&, const From&, const mpl_::int_<1>&, const mpl_::int_<0>&) [with To = boost::multiprecision::backends::cpp_dec_float<50u>; From = boost::multiprecision::backends::cpp_int_backend<128u, 128u, (boost::multiprecision::cpp_integer_type)0u, (boost::multiprecision::cpp_int_check_type)0u, void>]'
/usr/local/include/boost/multiprecision/number.hpp:108:7:   required from 'boost::multiprecision::number<Backend, ExpressionTemplates>::number(const boost::multiprecision::number<Other, ET>&, typename boost::enable_if_c<(! boost::multiprecision::detail::is_explicitly_convertible<Other, Backend>::value)>::type*) [with Other = boost::multiprecision::backends::cpp_int_backend<128u, 128u, (boost::multiprecision::cpp_integer_type)0u, (boost::multiprecision::cpp_int_check_type)0u, void>; boost::multiprecision::expression_template_option ET = (boost::multiprecision::expression_template_option)0u; Backend = boost::multiprecision::backends::cpp_dec_float<50u>; boost::multiprecision::expression_template_option ExpressionTemplates = (boost::multiprecision::expression_template_option)1u; typename boost::enable_if_c<(! boost::multiprecision::detail::is_explicitly_convertible<Other, Backend>::value)>::type = void]'
mp2.cpp:11:55:   required from here
/usr/local/include/boost/multiprecision/cpp_int/misc.hpp:94:4: error: no type named 'type' in 'struct boost::enable_if_c<false, bool>'
In file included from /usr/local/include/boost/multiprecision/cpp_int.hpp:18:0,
                 from mp2.cpp:1:
/usr/local/include/boost/multiprecision/detail/generic_interconvert.hpp: In instantiation of 'void boost::multiprecision::detail::generic_interconvert(To&, const From&, const mpl_::int_<1>&, const mpl_::int_<0>&) [with To = boost::multiprecision::backends::cpp_dec_float<50u>; From = boost::multiprecision::backends::cpp_int_backend<128u, 128u, (boost::multiprecision::cpp_integer_type)0u, (boost::multiprecision::cpp_int_check_type)0u, void>]':
/usr/local/include/boost/multiprecision/number.hpp:108:7:   required from 'boost::multiprecision::number<Backend, ExpressionTemplates>::number(const boost::multiprecision::number<Other, ET>&, typename boost::enable_if_c<(! boost::multiprecision::detail::is_explicitly_convertible<Other, Backend>::value)>::type*) [with Other = boost::multiprecision::backends::cpp_int_backend<128u, 128u, (boost::multiprecision::cpp_integer_type)0u, (boost::multiprecision::cpp_int_check_type)0u, void>; boost::multiprecision::expression_template_option ET = (boost::multiprecision::expression_template_option)0u; Backend = boost::multiprecision::backends::cpp_dec_float<50u>; boost::multiprecision::expression_template_option ExpressionTemplates = (boost::multiprecision::expression_template_option)1u; typename boost::enable_if_c<(! boost::multiprecision::detail::is_explicitly_convertible<Other, Backend>::value)>::type = void]'
mp2.cpp:11:55:   required from here
/usr/local/include/boost/multiprecision/rational_adaptor.hpp:252:13: note: template<class IntBackend> bool boost::multiprecision::backends::eval_is_zero(const boost::multiprecision::backends::rational_adaptor<IntBackend>&)
/usr/local/include/boost/multiprecision/rational_adaptor.hpp:252:13: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
In file included from /usr/local/include/boost/multiprecision/number.hpp:22:0,
                 from /usr/local/include/boost/multiprecision/cpp_int.hpp:12,
                 from mp2.cpp:1:
/usr/local/include/boost/multiprecision/detail/generic_interconvert.hpp:43:4: note:   'boost::multiprecision::backends::cpp_int_backend<128u, 128u, (boost::multiprecision::cpp_integer_type)0u, (boost::multiprecision::cpp_int_check_type)0u, void>' is not derived from 'const boost::multiprecision::backends::rational_adaptor<IntBackend>'
```

The server runs g++ 4.7.2 and boost 1.56, on a 64 bits CPU. I have installed the same g++ and boost version to see if this was the issue, but it is not.

From experimenting with the source, problems arise whenever I try to cast integers to float. However, as mentionned [in the documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_56_0/libs/multiprecision/doc/html/boost_multiprecision/tut/conversions.html), this is the proper way to do this.

Does anybody know how what the problem is, and how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know this library, but it seems that the problem comes from a bug (?) with the x86-64 architecture.

It should be noted that :

1. I have the same issue with my 64 bits OS (Linux Mint 16 - g++ 4.8.1 - boost 1.53).
2. As a workaround, you can cross-compile your code to a 32 bits binary with the -m32 flag (tested with success).
3. The issue disappears using cpp_int intead of uint128_t.
4. Strangely, there are no compilation errors using the following custom type:

   ```
   typedef number<cpp_int_backend<128, 128, signed_magnitude, unchecked, std::allocator<limb_type> > > t128_custom;
   ```

   Problems appear when this allocator is replaced by void (as defined by uint128_t), or when usigned_magnitude is used.

Maybe you should contact the boost community for further informations.